# expected ; before 'p' in arduino

Tags: arduino

i have a peice of example code for the TFT touch screen library for arduino:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>
#include <TFT.h>

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(57, A1, A2, 54, 300); 

void setup()
{
    Tft.init(); 
    pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    Point p = ts.getPoint();
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, 240, 0);
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, 320, 0);
}
```

but it returns this error:

> sketch_jun24a.ino:79:11: error: expected ';' before 'p'

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Use of `TSPoint` instead of `Point`**

The latest version of the TouchScreen library has renamed the `Point` class to `TSPoint`. Therefore, you had to use `TSPoint` instead of `Point`. Another point is that you should define `TS_MINX`, `TS_MAXX`, `TS_MINY`and `TS_MAXY`. I think you need something like that:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>
#include <TFT.h>

#define TS_MINX 140
#define TS_MAXX 900
#define TS_MINY 120
#define TS_MAXY 940

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(57, A1, A2, 54, 300); 

void setup()
{
    Tft.init(); 
    pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, 240, 0);
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, 320, 0);
}
```

If you use a TFT Touch Shield V1.0 from Seeed Studio or a similar hardware you can also check the [wiki-page](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/2.8''_TFT_Touch_Shield_V1.0) of the module with comprehensive examples.

Comment: yes i have i just edited the most of the sketch out to save space. http://pastebin.com/QSJv3Kwm

Comment: Ah, ok. I think your problem is the Point class, which is renamed to TSPoint in the latest version (see updated answers above). Try to change the class.